# Noise with heavy tails

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, noise

The main type of noise I know other than white noise is a colored noise (Ornstein-Uhlenbeck) of the form:

$$d\eta = \lambda \eta dt + \alpha dW_t$$

with exponential correlation. I'm interested in noise in which the distribution is heavy tailed so that events far from the mean are more common, and have much longer tails in the correlation function so that correlations last much longer than the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process (I'm unsure if this correlation and heavy tailed noise coincide or not). I believe this is also called "pink noise". Is there a known stochastic differential equation of the form:

$$dP(t) = f(P(t))dt + g(P(t))dW_t$$

describing such a process? (I'm using $P$ for pink noise).

Comment: Any SDE of that form will have a solution given by a Gaussian process, so you won't get heavy tailing. Anyway, do you want the resulting process to have continuous paths? I am not sure whether that requirement is even possible. If you don't necessarily want continuous paths, then there are lots of options in the form of Levy processes.

Comment: @Ian It would be ideal to find a process which is continuous and has tails decaying slower than an exponential (I was looking at this but not sure if this is what I'm hoping for: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/1/f_noise#A_stochastic_differential_equation_model).

Comment: Breiman's Probability  chapters 14-16 discusses some of these issues.  Probably other work that looks at Ito processes may also be relevant.